# Getting XPATH for element in safari

Tags: xpath, safari

Using Chrome, I can get the path to an element. I select "View source" and then right-click on the relevant item and say "get XPath".

In Safari, I can view the source, and when my cursor's on an element in the source, I can see the xpath visually displayed as a list of elements.. but I can't find a way to  get the text for that xpath. Surely there's some way (he said optimistically).

Comment: Wait, me too! Nobody has answered this question. Does anyone know how to copy the xpath for an element when using Safari?

Answer (score 3):

This turns out to be easy, and I don't know why I didn't see it. In Windows at least:

1. Ctrl-U to display page source (or right-click on the page and click "View page source" in the popup menu).
2. In the page source, right-click on the element you like; in the resulting popup, click the "Copy >" option
3. Select "Copy XPath" from the resulting nested popup.

See picture below for an illustration. Everything was done with right-clicks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late with an answer, but you might want to consider [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy) by google.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good Extension for Safari and Google Chrome:
https://github.com/sergeche/xmlview#readme

- Safari Extension: http://files.chikuyonok.ru/xv/xv.safariextz
- Google Chrome Extension: [download](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeocglpgjdpaefaedpblffpeebgmgddk)

**Current features**

- **Collapsable elements:** Alt+click to expand/collapse all descendant elements
- **Outline** for better document overview
- **Search by name or XPath**. By default uses simple search mode which looks for a partial match in element‘s or attribute’s name; use special symbols like ‘/’ or ‘[’ to search by XPath
- **Quick XPath mode:** hold down Command (Mac) or Ctrl (PC) key while moving mouse cursor over element‘s or attribute’s name to enter Quick
  XPath mode. Use Shift key to cycle through available XPath variants
  and then drag’n’drop element under cursor into text editor. Google
  Chrome users: click on element will copy XPath to clipboard